# VB Script to delete certain files and if files are found copy other files to directory

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a hard drive that is infected with a virus. The virus encrypts files and then asks for a ransom to unencrypt them. The files are HELP_DECRYPT.HTML, HELP_DECRYPT.PNG, HELP_DECRYPT.TXT and HELP_DECRYPT.URL.

There are thousands of infected files on the drive. I am trying to write a script to go through all the folders on the drive, and if it finds any of the malicious files it deletes them. I then want if to copy files from the backup drive in the same directory ie. if found in I\Folder\ if would get files from F\Folder\ .

In my case the infected drive is Y, and the backup drive is X.

I am relatively new to VBScripts and here is what I have so far:

```
    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubFolders FSO.GetFolder("Y:\"), 3

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, Depth)
    If Depth > 0 then
        For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
            'Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
    DeleteFiles(subFolder.path)
  On Error Resume Next
            ShowSubFolders Subfolder, Depth -1 

        Next
    End if
End Sub


  'deletes the malicious files and calls the copy function'
Function DeleteFiles(path)
'wscript.echo("in delete method")
  set FSO2 = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set ofolder = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set ofolder = FSO2.GetFolder(path)

  if FSO2.FileExists("HELP_DECRYPT.URL") Then
    ofolder.DeleteFile("HELP_DECRYPT.PNG")
    ofolder.DeleteFile("HELP_DECRYPT.HTML")
    ofolder.DeleteFile("HELP_DECRYPT.URL")
    ofolder.DeleteFile("HELP_DECRYPT.TXT")      
      wscript.echo("DeletedFiles")
  copyFiles(FSO.GetParentFolder) 
    end if

End Function


  'copies files from the backup'
Function CopyFiles(from)
    dim to1 'where we're copying to
    to1=from 'where we're copying from
    Call Replace (from, "Y:", "X:")
    SET FSO3 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each file In from 'not sure about "file"
        FSO3 = file
        Call FSO3.CopyFile (from, to1, true)'copies file and overwrites if already there
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would use:

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, badFiles
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
badFiles = Array("HELP_DECRYPT.PNG", "HELP_DECRYPT.URL", "HELP_DECRYPT.HTML", "HELP_DECRYPT.TXT")

Walk FSO.GetFolder("Y:\")

Sub Walk(folder)
  Dim subFolder
  For Each subFolder in folder.SubFolders
    DeleteFiles subFolder, badFiles
    RestoreFiles "X:", subFolder
    Walk subFolder
  Next
End Sub

Sub DeleteFiles(folder, filesToDelete)
  Dim file
  For Each file In filesToDelete
    file = FSO.BuildPath(folder.Path, file)
    If FSO.FileExists(file) Then FSO.DeleteFile file, True
  Next
End Sub

Sub RestoreFiles(sourceRoot, destinationFolder)
  Dim sourcePath, file
  WScript.Echo "Restoring " & destinationFolder.Path & " ..."
  sourcePath = Replace(destinationFolder.Path, destinationFolder.Drive, sourceRoot)
  If FSO.FolderExists(sourcePath) Then
    For Each file In FSO.GetFolder(sourcePath).Files
      WScript.Echo file.Name
      ' maybe add a DateLastModified check here?
      file.Copy FSO.BuildPath(destinationFolder.Path, file.Name), True
    Next
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Warning! Folder not found: " & sourcePath
  End If
End Sub
```

General tips for working with VBScript:

- Always use `Option Explicit`
- Avoid `On Error Resume Next` except in *very* closely confined situations. Simply suppressing any errors is never a good idea.
- Run scripts like the above on the command line with `cscript.exe` so you can see the script's `Echo` output without having to click at 1000's of message boxes.
- Use a global FSO object. No need to define a new one in every function
- Try to be generic. Look how `DeleteFiles()` `RestoreFiles()` above are actually not at all tailored to your current problem. You might be able to re-use those functions in a different script without having to change them.

Comment: Thanks that works great! The reason I was using the continue on error was because there is a folder that was holding mine up(Permissions errors). Any advice for getting around this?

Comment: Yes in that case you must use `On Error Resume Next`, but use it at function level, or better yet, at statement level, guarding exactly the one statement that can fail. Check `Err.Number` directly after (so you are only passing on known errors) and use `On Error Goto 0` as soon as possible to restore normal script behavior. Genuine, unexpected errors that go unnoticed because an overly broad `Resume Next` is in effect are a pain to debug. Scrutiny with error handling in VBS is paramount.